# Create a new admin for the spree app running on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, spree-auth-devise

I have my store running on heroku.

I need to create a new admin for the sotre.

How do I go about it? I am using `spree-auth-devise3.0.6`

Answer (score 1):

the question is not clear. Does it already have a admin ? If yes, you can use the panel

Do you want to used console to create a new admin.

if yes here is your code:

> heroku run rails console
>
> new_admin=Spree::User.create(:em=>"test@gmail.com", :password =>"testtest", :password_confirmation =>"testtest")
>
> new_admin.spree_roles<< Spree::Role.find_by(:name => "admin")
>
> new_admin.save

Answer (score 0):

- Log in as a current admin
- Select the user you want to become admin
- If the user doesn't already have an account, you can create one for them, or have them create one and then make them an admin
- Check the "admin" checkbox and click save or update